# Inheritance getter and toString() - java

Tags: java, inheritance, tostring, getter

I'm practicing inheritance in Java and got stuck on getter method in subclass.
Here is the Point class:

```
package OOP.LinePoint;

public class Point {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Point(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
     public String toString() {
          return "Point: (" + x + "," + y + ")";
       }
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

}
```

Here LineSub class:

```
package OOP.LinePoint;

public class LineSub extends Point{
    Point end;

    public LineSub(int beginX, int beginY, int endX, int endY){
        super(beginX, beginY);
        this.end = new Point(endX, endY);
    }
    public LineSub(Point begin, Point end){
        super(begin.getX(),begin.getY());
        this.end = end;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "LineSub [begin=" + "(" + super.getX() +"," + super.getY() +") " + "end=" + end + "]";
    }
    public Point getEnd() {
        return end;
    }
    public void setEnd(Point end) {
        this.end = end;
    }

    public Point getBegin(){

    }
    public void setBegin(Point begin){
        setX(begin.getX());
        setY(begin.getY());
    }

}
```

My problem:

1) toString() method. I'm trying to print two points(begin and end). As you can see end is easy but begin Point is inherited and idk what should I type. The way I'm getting x and y of point is working but for me it seems to be lame way of doing that. For sure there is a better way, could you please help me with that?

2) Point getBegin() method. I've tried:

```
public Point getBegin(){
  return (Point)this;
 }//Not working(getting whole Point object)
```

and

```
public Point getBegin(){
  return new Point(getX(), getY());
 }//Very noob way
```

I have no other ideas, please lend me your wisdom.

Comment: Shouldn't it be better to have 2 Point class variables? You are abusing inheritance by letting you LineSub extending from point... Is LineSub a Point?

Comment: Is a line a kind of a point?

Comment: LineSub is another point: A line is a point extended with another point

Comment: `getting whole Point object`, then what else do you expect from `getBegin()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the start `Point` you must cast yourself to a `Point`. You can call your `super.toString` to access the `toString` of the parent class.

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "LineSub [begin=" + super.toString() + "end=" + end.toString() + "]";
    }

    public Point getBegin() {
        return (Point) this;
    }
```

The fact that you have to cast is an indicator that you have your hierarchy wrong. This structure would normal be implemented using two points.

```
public class LineSub {

    Point begin;

    Point end;
```

Comment: When I create object like: LineSub l1 = new LineSub(new Point(1,1), new Point(2,2));
 and want to print just begin Point I get(l1.setBegin(new Point(3,3));):
LineSub [begin=Point: (1,1)end=Point: (2,2)]

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, it is not a good use of inheritance. Your case is not a valid candidate for Inheritance.
A class is a good candidate for inheritance only when it conforms to `is-A` relationship.

A `Line` is not a `Point` but it a collection of points (In your case it is being and end).

So, It is a good candidate for composition (`Has-A`).

A line `HAS` a begin and an end point. You are using both inheritance (For begin point) and composition (For end point) for code reuse.

Adhere to composition and have two points (begin and end) in Line class.

Comment: You see, I've done that with no problem(what you wrote above, but now my LineSub class is just another Point that extends Point class.

Comment: @seemlyMike, why are you extending Point class, you can just use 2 point object in LineSub class.

Comment: @seemlyMike I can see you're trying this as practice but it's a really weird thing to do and not something I could see you'd ever do in a real program.

Comment: @NamanGala Yes I know and you are right, but this exercise I did in 2 ways. First I did it with composition(everything work's like a charm) and next I tried to do same thing with inheritance.